How to resume SFTP download with Java ChannelSftp get
I have a file to download with ChannelSftp with Java.
channelSftp.get(string source, string destination);

It works fine.
I'd like to know if there's a disconnect, how to resume the download.
Thank you

To resume the download, just start it again with RESUME flag:
channelSftp.get(source, destination, null, ChannelSftp.RESUME);

The RESUME flag will make JSch query size of a partial local file and restart the transfer from there. If the file is already downloaded completely, it transfers nothing.
